# How to see if these congruence groups are normal

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let

$$\Gamma(N)=\left\{ \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) :  \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} \equiv  \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} \mod N \right\}$$

$$\Gamma_0(N)=\left\{ \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) :  \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} \equiv  \pmatrix{* & * \\ 0 & *} \mod N \right\}$$

$$\Gamma_1(N)=\left\{ \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) :  \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} \equiv  \pmatrix{1 & * \\ 0 & 1}\mod N \right\}.$$

I want to check whether these subgroups of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ are normal subgroups. The first one is easy, as I can find a surjective homomorphism, such that $\Gamma(N)$ is in the kernel for all $N\geq1$.

For the other groups, what is the smartest and shortest way to (dis)prove it?

Comment: Since $\Gamma(N)$ is a subgroup of the other two, your question is the same as asking if the mod $N$ images of the other two subgroups are normal in ${\rm SL}_2({\mathbf Z}/(n))$. Look at the general conjugate of such mod $N$ matrices and check if they again have the desired form. (You could also do it over ${\mathbf Z}$.)

Comment: May I ask what is that *'s in matrices?

Comment: A star in a matrix generally means that any valid entry is allowed. For $\Gamma_0$ it would perhaps have been clearer just to write $c \equiv 0 \mod N$.